# kivy - name Error name Thread is not defined

Tags: kivy

I have this code

```
from threading import Thread
...
Builder.load_string('''
<Urlpup>:
    size_hint: .7, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Enter URL'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        CustomTextInput:
            id: url_input
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: 'OK'    
            on_press: root.dismiss()
            on_release: Thread(target=app.create_new_article(url_input.text)).start()
''')
```

When running it I got Name Error name Thread is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import Thread in the kv context, see [the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#special-syntax).